# WPF binding expression in combination with Static or StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to use Static or StaticResource in a WPF binding expression to achieve something like this
IsChecked="{Binding MyArray[{StaticResource MyIntValue}].Value}" without using converter? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without a converter. The good news is that the converter is pretty trivial though!